# Question involving the application of the mean value theorem (MVT)

Tags: real-analysis

> Suppose that $f(0)=0$ and $f'$ is increasing. Prove that the function $g(x) = \frac{f(x)}{x}$ is increasing on $(0,\infty)$.

My attempt: We want to show that $g(a)<g(b)$. So first, we use the MVT on $f$. Suppose $a<b$ are any two points on $I$. Since $f'$ is increasing we know that $f(a)\leq f(b) \Rightarrow f(a) -f(b) \leq 0 $. By the MVT, there is some point $c\in(a,b)$ so that $f'(c) = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$. So $f(b) - f(a) = f'(c)(b-a) = xg(b)-xg(a) = f'(c)(b-a)$.

Then where do I go from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a<b$.  $g(a) = f^\prime(c)$ for some $c \in (0,a)$ by the mean value theorem for $f$ on $[0,a]$.  As you've observed, $bg(b) - ag(a) = f^\prime(d)(b-a)$ for some $d \in (a, b)$.  As $d>c$, we have $$g(b) = \frac{1}{b}((b-a)f^\prime(d) + af^\prime(c)) > \frac{1}{b}((b-a)f^\prime(c) + af^\prime(c)) = f^\prime(c) = g(a)$$ since $f^\prime$ is increasing.

Comment: I don't quite understand how you came up with the $g(a)=f'(c)$ part.

Comment: The mean value theorem for $f$ on $[0, a]$.  I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Actually, I'm having trouble understanding how you did the last line. Could you write down some more steps for it please?

Comment: The first equality comes from solving $bg(b) - ag(a) = f^\prime(d)(b-a)$ for $g(b)$ and using $f^\prime(c) = g(a)$.  The inequality comes from the fact that $f^\prime(d) > f^\prime(c)$ because $d>c$ and $f^\prime$ is increasing. The rest is just simplification.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. We have
 $$f(b) - f(a) = f'(c)(b-a)$$
Since $b>a$, we have $b-a\gt 0$. The sign on the LHS is solely decided by f$\prime (c)$. If f'(c)>0, f(b)-f(a)>0 or f(b)>f(a).

Comment: I fail to see how this helps...